# New button in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, button, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a lightning custom page and I need to include a New button to create a new record.

How to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Create a new record  in Lightning

> You may want to opens the page to create a new record for the
>   specified entityApiName, for example, “Account” or
>   “`myNamespace__MyObject__c`”.
>
> To display the record create page for an object, set the object name
>   on the entityApiName parameter and fire the event. recordTypeId is
>   optional and, if provided, specifies the record type for the created
>   object. This example displays the record create panel for contacts.

**Button**

```
<aura:component>
   <ui:button label="New" press="{!c.createRecord}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact"
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

**[For Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

If you are inside the lightning container ,there is a standard event to open lightning edit page

Here is the code

Component for button

```
<aura:component>
   <ui:button label="Edit Record" press="{!c.edit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

The JS helper

```
edit : function(component, event, helper) {
  var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
   editRecordEvent.setParams({
    "recordId": component.get("v.contact.Id")
   });
  editRecordEvent.fire();
}
```